# Error 91 when opening file Workbooks.Open(Filepath)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm facing a problem that I really don't understand.

I created a macro that opens a workbooks, reads some information in it, and closes it.

To open the workbook, I use these lines:

```
Path = Func_Use_File_DialogOpen()
If Path <> "" Then
    Set wb_chosen = Application.Workbooks.Open(Path, UpdateLinks:=0)
ElseIf Path = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Error, start again")
    Exit Sub
End If
```

For your information, the variable Path contains the whole path of the file, with the extension.

Example: `Path= C:\Users\alex\Desktop\file.xlsm`

On my computer, the macro works perfectly, it opens the worbook, and I can use it with my variable called `wb_chosen`

But when I send my macro to a coworker, he gets the error

> "RUNTIME ERROR 91: Object variable or With Block variable not set"

How is that possible? when I try to debug the macro on his computer, I see that the variable path is perfectly fine (like on my computer), but the variable `wb_chosen` is nothing

so the problem is on the line :

```
    Set wb_chosen = Application.Workbooks.Open(Path, UpdateLinks:=0)
```

Could it be the `Application.Workbooks` that doesn't work?
I really need this macro to work on every computer, is there a parameter to change on Excel? should I just put this instead?

```
Workbooks.Open(Path)
```

**FYI, here are some other details  about the code**

The workbook is declared like this

```
Public wb_chosen As Workbook
```

the function Func_Use_File_DialogOpen() is as follow:

```
Public Function Func_Use_File_DialogOpen() As String
 
On Error GoTo lblErr

   With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        Func_Use_File_DialogOpen = .SelectedItems(1)
   End With
   
   Exit Function
   
lblErr:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
    Func_Use_File_DialogOpen = vbNullString
    
End Function
```

The variable Path is a string that store the full path of the file. When I run the code on my computer, i have

```
Path=\\cm\TA\PNL\10 - octobre\pnl_Octobre.xlsm
```

Comment: What is the body of `Func_Use_File_DialogOpen()` function?

Comment: What is the exact path in case of error? I guess it is not exactly `C:\Users\alex\Desktop\file.xlsm`. If you cannot show that create a fake path/file that defenitley produces that error. How are your variables declared? Make sure `Option Explicit` is used and show your variable declarations.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your responses, I edited my post with the informations requested.
However, I cannot show you an example of code that produces the error, because it works fine on my computer. When my coworker runs the macro, he chooses the SAME file as me, on the same shared repository.
I have the feeling that it might be because of Application.Workbook but I'm not experienced enough to know what to do

Comment: We all use Windows 10, same Excel Version (2016)
I don't understand, path separators are always backslashes for me, like this "C:\Program Files (x86)"

We use french computers, but I don't think it can change something

Comment: @AlexandreMich forget it my bad. Too less coffee here ^^

Comment: Does it happen with all files or only files is some specific path? Actually it should have something to do with the file or path since the code looks good (and even more it works for you).

Comment: My coworker just told me that he has already succesfully opened a file with that same macro
So, yes you're right it must have something to do with the path
I realise it's gonna be hard for you to diagnose my problem, don't worry, I'm gonna keep exploring solutions

Comment: So then I think the idea is to find out the difference between a path that worked and one that didn't. I guess this is the only way to get closer to the issue. • And yes, always difficult to diagnose if the issue is not in the code shown in the question but elsewhere.

Comment: Yes I'll have to see on my coworker laptop, after the quarantine...
I'll come back to post an answer if I found one.

Thank you for you help, you reassured me that the problem was not in the code. Have a great day !